# OnConfiguring has gone missing

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm attempting to update to EF7 beta5.

The compiler tells me that OnConfiguring is no longer a suitable method to override.  It also tells me that it can no longer find DbContextOptions or DbContextOptionsBuilder.

Seems like i'm missing something here.  Can anyone enlighten me as to what this might be?

```
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        string cnString = Config.Get("Data:" + _cnNm + ":ConnectionString");

        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(cnString);

    }
```

Comment: Update from? It was temporarily named EntityOptionsBilder...

Comment: that was the solution.  much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot override OnConfiguring in beta5 - no suitable method found to override](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31336007/cannot-override-onconfiguring-in-beta5-no-suitable-method-found-to-override)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was temporarily named EntityOptionsBuilder, in beta 6 it is back to DbContextOptionsBuilder again